# Method Actions and how to assign them

Tags: java, methods

I am nearly done with a project but with little guidance I am unsure as to whether or not I'm correct. The code below ends with three methods with parameters but I was not sure what to do with them or how to respond to the comment "give them something to do". Any suggestions? Are there more than one option? Thanks.

```
public class Banktest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount SM = new BankAccount("Sam", "Gamgee");
        System.out.println(SM.firstname + SM.lastname);
        SM.setAccountbalance();
        SM.setAccountNumber();
        System.out.println(SM.firstname + " " + SM.lastname 
           + " " + SM.accountbalance + " " + SM.accountnumber);
    }
}
```

BankAccount class

```
public class BankAccount {

    public String firstname;
    public double accountbalance;
    public String lastname;
    public int accountnumber;

    public BankAccount() {
    }

    public BankAccount(String firstname, String lastname, int accountnumber) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.accountnumber = accountnumber;
        this.accountbalance = 0;
    }

    public BankAccount(String firstname, String lastname, 
        int accountnumber, double accountbalance) {

        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.accountnumber = accountnumber;
        this.accountbalance = accountbalance;
    }

    public BankAccount(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void setName(String firstname, String lastname) {
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(int accountnumber) {
    }

    public void setAccountbalance(double accountbalance) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post above and post well formatted code. Surely your real code isn't all left justified, and you must agree that if you're asking for volunteer assistance, it's not asking too much for you to first put in some effort to help make your code readable, right?

Comment: sorry is not possible to say whatever ....,

Answer (score 1):

Your BankAccount class has member variables for firstname and last name. Furthermore, when calling your methods you must provide the parameters as the signature expects.

Calling setName on an instance of BankAccount should set the name, surely?

```
this.firstname = firstname;
this.lastname = lastname;
```

For the account number and balance this is similar.

The methods you have created, or been given, are called mutators/setters. Your member variables should be private really or accessible via specific accessors/getters.

The following link should help your understanding: -

http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/accessormutator.htm

**Slightly more simple explanation**

If you imagine you are a software developer for a very simple banking application. That person would require a bank account. The bank account must belong to someone and must have a bank account number. When writing software you may have to consider the case that once you have a bank account object that has been constructed with a person's personal details, it may be, in certain circumstances, required to allow these variables to change. By creating methods such as 'setName', you are allowing the name to be changed without affecting other parts of the object, such as the bank account number.

At the moment, your setName method, and the other two do nothing. They must be given something to do for them to be useful. You wouldn't like to go into a bank and ask for your name to be changed, only for them to not actually do anything! ;-)

Comment: chrisw69, I had that solution written down! I guess I was second guessing myself and it seemed too simple to be right. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, make sure you get yourself a good java book and you'll be on your way! :-)

Comment: chrisw69, Are there any that you would recommend. My teacher isn't working from one and some of the exercise that I've had are kinda abstract. If I can find visual ideas to connect the concepts (like you used above) I can nail it. Thanks again.

Comment: http://jyops.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/top-10-java-books-you-dont-want-to-miss.html might help you.. Not sure about the visual ideas though; I just made that stuff up to help you.